# React when i create dynamic component with remove button remove button does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I create a dynamic component  textbox and remove button for eact textbox,
I have a problem when remove spcific textbox it remove all next items. for example if if have list of objects has 8 object  if i remove object number 4 it remove 4,5,6,7,8

```
function PhoneObject(props) {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="col-2 float-left">
          <img
            className="remove-img"
            height="25px"
            width="25px"
            alt=""
            onClick={() => removePhone(props.index)}
            src={require("../../../utilities/images/icons/add-new.png")}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="col-10 float-right">
          <div className="form-group">
            <input type="text" className="form-control form-control-sm" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }


const [phoneItem, setPhoneItem] = useState([{}]);

  function addNewPhone() {
    let item = {
      index: phoneItem.length,
      obj: <PhoneObject index={phoneItem.length} />,
    };
    setPhoneItem([...phoneItem, item]);
  }

  function removePhone(key) {
    console.log("removied itex: " + key);
    let items = phoneItem;
    let newitem = items.filter((s) => s.index !== key);
    console.log(newitem);
    setPhoneItem(items);
  }

return (
   {phoneItem.map((obj, i) => {
          return (
            <div className="row" key={i}>
              {obj.index}
              {obj.obj}
            </div>
          );
        })}
)
```

Comment: In `removePhone` you call `setPhoneItem(items)` - shouldn't this be `setPhoneItem(newItem)`?

Comment: Also, if you can, show how and where you are calling `addNewPhone`, because it seems likely that you are calling it with outdated state values.

Comment: I call new item problem still exist . I called item to prove that any delete button show deferent list each delete item show it self as the end of list